# Database Integration within the software

Tags: java

I know how to use mysql database using hibernate. Now, I want to make the application such that the application works on other computers also when I run the program in other computers. So, how can i integrate the database  within the software. Thank you

I have no idea.

Comment: are you talking about having an embebed DBMS alogn with app? if that is the case i would suggest to take a look at http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html. Bear in mind that in that case each distribution will have diferent data base, don't very well how to "share" data, although i believe that it is possible.

Comment: This question gives very small information and too broad to discuss. What do you mean by application that works on other computers? Also what do you mean by integrate database with software?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use something like SQLite. take a look on [About SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)